# TypeError: undefined is not an object ( evaluating 'warnings.length')

Tags: reactjs, react-native, gradle

This error is occurring with a fresh installation of React native version 0.58.4 on MacOs and app running on OnePlus6T.

[image]

Gradle version: 5.4.1

Never happened earlier, Also when ran on Andriod studio Gradle sync is failing in finding the gradle classpath 3.6.1 on Jc center.

When the debug mode is on it seems to work. but when remoteJs debug is stopped it again gives this error.

Link to Github issue raised ( Unsolved ): https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/28588

Comment: did you find any solution to this

Comment: Have you resolve this issue @kai

Comment: I got the same issue and it is so confusing I don't know what is causing it.

Comment: No guys, didn't find the solution yet. Have raised the issue on Github and waiting for the Maintainers to comment about what changed and what can be done.

Comment: Currently used 0.59 as its closest version that works also not major support changes for most of the packages.